# How to display alert message on submit for ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to display an alert message once a form is submitted.

```
$('#submitForm').on('click' , function(){

                var markers = {
                    "username": $('#username').val(),
                    "topic": $('#topic').val(),
                    "date": $('#date').val().toString(),
                    "time": $('#time').val().toString(),
                };

                $.ajax({
                        url:"http://127.0.0.1:8080/latest/video/user",
                        method:"POST",
                        data: JSON.stringify(markers),
                        dataType: "json",
                        encode: true,
                        processData: false,
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': "application/json"
                        },
                        success: function(data){
                         alert("New record is successfully added!");  
                         }
                    })
            });
```

The data is submitted successfully but it doesn't display the alert message.

Comment: Because the data is submitted "normally" and the page reloads... add an `e` as argument in `$('#submitForm').on('click' , function(e){` and add `e.preventDefault();` right under.

Comment: Returned datatype is JSON right?

Comment: @TusharShahi yes it is